# Groupby all non-numeric columns and print the resulting dataframe aggregated by averages

Tags: python, pandas

I have to group it by all non-numeric columns(numeric columns would be float and int) and print the resulting dataframe aggregated by averages.
The output should be first five rows of the resultant dataframe after the groupby operation.

input: csv file

output:

```
                                                                        Sentiment_Polarity  \
App                    Translated_Review                      Sentiment                       
10 Best Foods for You 10 best foods 4u Excellent chose foods Positive                 1.00   
                      A big thanks ds I got bst gd health    Positive                 0.10   
                      Absolutely Fabulous Phenomenal         Positive                 0.45   
                      Amazing                                Positive                 0.60   
                      An excellent A useful                  Positive                 0.65
```

```
                                                                     Sentiment_Subjectivity  
App                   Translated_Review                      Sentiment                          
10 Best Foods for You 10 best foods 4u Excellent chose foods Positive                     0.65  
                     A big thanks ds I got bst gd health    Positive                     0.15  
                     Absolutely Fabulous Phenomenal         Positive                     0.75  
                     Amazing                                Positive                     0.90  
                     An excellent A useful                  Positive                     0.50
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using [`pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html), exclude all the numeric columns, so you get the `string` or `object` type columns:

```
groupcols = df.select_dtypes(exclude="number").columns.tolist()
group_df = df.groupby(groupcols).mean() #.reset_index()
```

You can reset the index if you want to after these steps.

You can also use the following to get only categorial columns:

```
groupcols = df.select_dtypes(include="category").columns.tolist()
```

Please read the documentation on how to include/exclude the `dtypes` that you want.

#### EDIT:

If your original dataframe is a `MultiIndex` dataframe, you will need to do this as the **first step**:

```
# MultiIndex to columns
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: @jezrael Edit what you're not comfortable with, or if you have anything to make it better